# AWS CDK (.NET) How to modify RDS Cluster Security Group to allow access from other Security Groups (e.g. EC2, Lambda)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

Using AWS CDK (.NET), I am creating an EC2 instance and a Lambda (with its own execution Security Group) as well as an Aurora PostgresSQL RDS Cluster.  When connecting the pieces manually, I would also have created a Security Group to RDP into EC2.  Lastly I would modify the RDS Cluster Security Group to allow all traffic from the EC2 Security Group as well as from the Lambda Execution Security Group.

Trying to re-create the same in AWS CDK (.NET), I am unable to get access to the RDS Cluster Security Group to modify it to allow traffic from the EC2 Security Group or the Lambda Execution Security Group.  How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually rather than thinking in terms of Security Groups, I have resolved this question by allowing connections from my lambda to the RDS cluster like so:

```csharp
Function.Connections.AllowTo(props.Cluster, Port.Tcp(5432), $"Allow inbound traffic from Lambda on 5432");
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html, you use the

Amazon.CDK.AWS.RDS.OptionConfiguration.SecurityGroups

```
securityGroups? ISecurityGroup[]    Optional list of security groups to use for this option, if vpc is specified.
```